# RegEx to match lines consisting of whitespace only

Tags: java, regex, string

I've gone through multiple expressions for hours but can't quite get one to match what I need exactly.

If I have the following input:

```
Hi



This


Is



A

Test
```

I am trimming it to:

```
Hi

This

Is

A

Test
```

---

All is good when the blank lines length are 0 (no `String`) however some inputs contains a few spaces `("     ")` within those blank lines and thus would like to check whether a string has 0:infinite number of whitespaces but no characters (simply a blank line).

```
ArrayList<Integer> listOfBlanks = new ArrayList<>();  
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        if(arrayList.get(i).isEmpty()) {
            if(arrayList.get(i+1).isEmpty())
                listOfBlanks.add(i+1);
    }
}
```

`String#isEmpty` is only good when there are no whitespaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `string.trim().isEmpty()` to check for length 0 after trimming *leading and trailing* whitespaces.

Comment: God how did that not cross my mind.. I feel like a complete idiot now haha. Thank you. EDIT - Works as expected, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression to do so would be `s.matches("\\s*")`. `\\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters.